# Skipping over inputting value to drop down menu when not available

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

Depending on who logs in the page changes from a field having a drop down menu to the field not having a drop down menu and I want my program to ignore that field when the drop down menu is not available. What I have now is this (customCoverageCell targets a cell in Excel)

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+ customCoverageCell +"')]/following::select")));
            if((!customValueCell.equals("") && !driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+ customCoverageCell +"')]/following::select")).isEmpty())){
                dropDown.selectByValue(customValueCell);
}
```

but it will try to change the drop down menu.
I've tried this

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+ customCoverageCell +"')]/following::select")));
            if((!customValueCell.equals("") && driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+ customCoverageCell +"')]/following::select")).isEnabled())){//also tried isDisplayed and isSelected just to see if it actually would do anything 
                dropDown.selectByValue(customValueCell);
}
```

How would I get it to not try to input a value without making sure the value in excel is blank?

Here is the HTML in question:
**WITHOUT DROP DOWN**

```html
<div class="wrap-padding-sm">
  <div class="threeCols">
    <div class="colContent">
      <div class="sub-colContent">
        <span class="checkmark-grey">
            </span>
        <span class="checkTitle">Third Party (THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO TARGET AND WORK FROM)
           </span>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-colContent">Limit:
        <span class="amount-midCol">$$$$$$$$$$$$
            </span>
      </div><span class="scroogeMsg h7 mobile-show">Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="colContent">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" class="margin-R10" data-target="#cust_standard_scrooge_0">
        <span>What this covers
          </span>
      </a>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cust_standard_scrooge_0" class="btn-accordian collapsed"> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="cust_standard_scrooge_0" class="scrooge-wrap collapse">
    <p>Some text
    </p>
  </div><span class="scroogeMsg h7 mobile-hide">Some text</span>
</div>
```

**WITH DROP DOWN**

```html
<div class="wrap-padding-sm">
  <div class="threeCols">
    <div class="colContent">
      <div class="sub-colContent">
        <span class="checkmark-grey">
            </span>
        <span class="checkTitle">Third Party  (THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO TARGET AND WORK FROM)
           </span>
        <span class="checkTitle_sub">Some text
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="sub-colContent">
        <div class="select-dropWrap">

          <div id="h_abc194" class="form-group form-group-lg            "><label for="changeScrooge:h_abc161:0:h_abc194:select-one-menu" class="control-label">Limit: </label>
            <div class="select-dropMenu  ">
              <div class="selector uniform-select fixedWidth" id="uniform-changeScrooges:h_abc161:0:h_abc194:select-one-menu"><span style="user-select: none;">1000000</span><select id="changeScrooges:h_abc161:0:h_abc194:select-one-menu" name="changeScrooges:h_abc161:0:h_abc194:select-one-menu" class="form-control input-lg  " size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','changeScrooges:custom_standard_scrooges','changeScrooges:custom_standard_scrooges changeScrooges:customAcceptDeclinePNL',{'onevent':recommendedScroogeAfterAJAX})"> 
    <option value="1000000" selected="selected">1000000</option>
 <option value="2000000">2000000</option>
</select></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><span class="scroogeMsg h7 mobile-show">Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="colContent">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" class="margin-R10" data-target="#cust_standard_scrooge_0">
        <span>What text?
          </span>
      </a>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cust_standard_scrooge_0" class="btn-accordian collapsed"> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="cust_standard_scrooge_0" class="scrooge-wrap collapse">
    <p>Some text
    </p>
  </div><span class="scroogeMsg h7 mobile-hide">Sme text</span>
</div>
```

All the black spots are just text fields that had to be blacked out
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the small trick that i always used to find the existence of an element.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("")).size()>0)
{
   //Element actually exists
   //Do the Stuff
}
else
{
   //Element doesn't exist
   //Do the stuff if any
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason it thinks it exists and tries to do it even though the drop down no longer exists. I have a feeling `/following::select` targets the next drop down menu on the page.

Comment: That means, the xpath might not unique. Try to write an unique xpath for the element. Can i have the sire url pls?

Comment: Yeah. I have go from the text field since the id changes for every different log ins. Tried using ancestor, parent, child etc but things keep changing.

Comment: Can i have the site details dude?

Comment: its internal access only unfortunately. All I can do is the HTML above. I've added where I need to target and work from.

Comment: Does this tag appears only once in the html with drop down?  <div class="select-dropMenu  ">

Comment: Appears multiple times. Has to be by the text field. I'll put up a picture of a section.

Comment: So can we keep the text box as reference and from there, can we navigate to the respective drop down? I am not able to do this without being live. What is the xpath you have written for the dd?

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+ customCoverageCell +"')]/following::select"))`

Comment: Is there more than one customcoveragecell in the dom?

Comment: customCoverageCell takes it's information from an excel file. Third Party is one example it takes. It works fine when there is a drop down menu available. I can always leave the cell in the excel file blank to avoid this issue. Was hoping there was another solution though.